# how to create a chart in angularjs with database data?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, charts

I am trying to creating a Bar chart.I'm using this bar chart as a reference [Here](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/).
this is my HTML part..

```
<body ng-app="app">
   <div ng-controller="BarCtrl">
     <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" width=100% height=25
     chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series"></canvas>
   </div>
```

And this is my angularjs part...

```
<script>
angular.module("app",["chart.js"]).controller("BarCtrl", function ($http,$scope) {
  $http.get("../widget/stock_details.php").success(function(data){
            $scope.data=data;
            //$scope.tqnt=data.tqnt;
            //$scope.old_quantity=data.old_quantity;

  $scope.labels = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul','Aug','Sep'];
  $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];


  $scope.data = [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
                [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90];
});
  });
```

If I want my database data in $scope.data and $scope.labels then what should I do?I'd try this 
`$scope.data = [ [data[0],data[2],data[4],data[6]] , [data[1],data[3],data[5]] ];` but this is not a good way so what it could be?

php file is..

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
$er=new Connect();
$er->__construct();

    $data=array();

    $selct=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  stock");

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($selct))
        {
             $data[]=$row['total_qnt'];
            $data[]=$row['old_quantity'];
          $data[]=$row['stock_date];
        }

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: `$data[0][]=$row['total_qnt'];
 $data[1][]=$row['old_quantity'];` then parse it into your javascript code and pass to `$scope.data` and check

Comment: @Anant Thanks it's working the way you said.

Comment: Krish glad to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is:-

change `while` part like below:-

`$data[0][]=$row['total_qnt'];
 $data[1][]=$row['old_quantity'];`

then parse this `json encoded data` to `array` into your `javascript` code and pass to `$scope.data`.

Comment: One more thing if I want to make my $scope.labels value also a dynamic then what to do.I've edited my question can you look at it please.

Comment: you need to add all things like labels and series to your `$data` array and then pass corresponding sub-array to labels and series and data.